# How can I get full resolution on Mac Book Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, resolution

I am using a Mac Book Pro 15" retina display which supposedly has a 2880x1800 resolution, but I don't seem to be getting that many pixels.  In the control panel, if I choose the `Scaled` radio button the farthest setting to the right says `looks like 1920x1200`, how can I get the complete resolution?